# How to remove all string or numbers after certain Character in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

good Evening, i have been scraping amazon site in sneakers section.

now i get two prices in range that  means 1100 - 2300

How can i remove everything from the - to the end in Pandas and also the currency symbol. this is what i have tried and my respective output

The csv File

https://easyupload.io/ayaivg

```
import pandas as pd

Azs = pd.read_csv("amazsneakers.csv")

Azs['Price'].str.replace("-","")
```

Output:

[image: Pandas]

Comment: Can you add sample input as well?

Comment: hi do you mean the csv file ??

Comment: `Azs['Price'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[0])`

Comment: hi i get error after applying that.   'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: @Firaki12345, not the CSV file but few rows(3-5) should be enough.

Comment: hi i just did it with the above lambda function. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split by spaces with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then select second splitted values, remove `,` and convert to numeric:

```
Azs = pd.read_csv("amazsneakers.csv")

Azs['Price'] = Azs['Price'].str.split().str[1].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

Or first remove `,` and extract floats by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
Azs['Price'] = Azs['Price'].str.replace(',','').str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)').astype(float)

print (Azs['Price'])

0      645.0
1      655.0
2      799.0
3      799.0
4      849.0
 
169    367.0
170    199.0
171    386.0
172    499.0
173    401.0
Name: Price, Length: 174, dtype: float64
```

Comment: hi i just did it with the above lambda function. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

```
test_string = "ab-cd"

split_string = test_string.split("-", 1)

#Split into "ab" and "cd"

required_string = split_string[0]

print(required_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Azs['Price'] = Azs['Price'].apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[0])